# what can change extension .txt to .HTML files with ruby

Tags: ruby

I have many iles look like `index.txt  hello.txt` can change extension txt to HTML using ruby . can using `Dir` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when open [Dir in Ruby Doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html)

`Dir` directory streams representing directories in the underlying file system

`glob` use to match file

`Dir.glob('*.txt').each { |files| File.rename(files, files.sub('txt', 'html')) }`